# Replace items in a Python list from another list

Tags: python

Lets say I have two lists,

```
l1 = ['Join', 'logsource1.selection1', 'and', 'logsource2.selection3', 'AND', '((logsource1.selection2', '<=', 'contraint1)', 'AND', '(logsource2.selection4', '<=', 'constraint1))']
l2 = ['logsource1=Zscaler/Proxy', 'logsource2=Proofpoint/TAP']
```

How do I take the values from l2 and replace in l1, something like this,

```
l3 = ['Join', 'Zscaler/Proxy.selection1', 'and', 'logsource2=Proofpoint/TAP.selection3', 'AND', '((Zscaler/Proxy.selection2', '<=', 'contraint1)', 'AND', '(Proofpoint/TAP.selection4', '<=', 'constraint1))']
```

Comment: Shouldn't the fourth entry in l3 be "Proofpoint/TAP.selection3"? Or the second one "logsource1=Zscaler/Proxy.selection1"?

Comment: Are you looking to replace whole "words", so that for example `logsource10` in l1 would not be replaced by the `logsource1=...` in l2? If so, what characters can be in these "words"?

Comment: @Christian that was a typo I edited the code.

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason that you want your second input to be in the form of a list of 'key=value' strings? A dictionary would seem to be a more natural type to store this information.

Comment: Isn't there a typo still? Why is the fourth element in l3 `logsource2=Proofpoint/TAP.selection3` instead of `Proofpoint/TAP.selection3`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
l2 = list(map(lambda x: x.split("="), l2))

def func(arr, el):
    if(len(el)==0):
        return list(arr)
    else:
        return func(map(lambda x: x.replace(*el[0]), arr), el[1:])

l1=func(l1, l2)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> l1

['Join', 'Zscaler/Proxy.selection1', 'and', 'Proofpoint/TAP.selection3', 'AND', '((Zscaler/Proxy.selection2', '<=', 'contraint1)', 'AND', '(Proofpoint/TAP.selection4', '<=', 'constraint1))']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a helping dictionary should do the trick:

```
l1 = ['Join', 'logsource1.selection1', 'and', 'logsource2.selection3', 'AND', '((logsource1.selection2', '<=', 'contraint1)', 'AND', '(logsource2.selection4', '<=', 'constraint1))']
l2 = ['logsource1=Zscaler/Proxy', 'logsource2=Proofpoint/TAP']

l_help = {split_result[0]: split_result[1] for split_result in [e.split("=") for e in l2]}

l3 = l1.copy()

for key, value in l_help.items():
    l3 = [e.replace(key, value) for e in l3]
```

Output is:

```
['Join', 'Zscaler/Proxy.selection1', 'and', 'Proofpoint/TAP.selection3', 'AND', '((Zscaler/Proxy.selection2', '<=', 'contraint1)', 'AND', '(Proofpoint/TAP.selection4', '<=', 'constraint1))']
```

Comment: I came to the same answer. FWIW, you can also do `l_help = dict((s.split('=') for s in l2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
l1 = ['Join', 'logsource1.selection1', 'and', 'logsource2.selection3', 'AND', '((logsource1.selection2', '<=', 'contraint1)', 'AND', '(logsource2.selection4', '<=', 'constraint1))']
l2 = ['logsource1=Zscaler/Proxy', 'logsource2=Proofpoint/TAP']
l3=[]
for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        k,v=j.split("=")
        if k in i:
            l3.append(i.replace(k,v))
            break
    else:
        l3.append(i)
```